# Unable to send/parse JSON using Worklight adapter and wink/jackson restful

Tags: json, jackson, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, apache-wink

**Background:** I am using a Worklight adapter to consume restful service. `Apache wink` is my restful implementation servlet. I have used `jackson` related jars in my service.

**Problem:** If I try to consume service with `form-urlencoded` type, it runs smoothly. However when I try to consume `JSON`, it fails with parse exception on the first character of JSON string sent from adapter.

Relevant implementation and exception, below.

Adapter code to consume service (runs in worklight server):

```
var input = {
   method : 'post',
   returnedContentType : 'json',        
   path : loginRequestPath,

   headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
   parameters:{“commonname": username, "password" : password }
 };
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

Jackson registration ([copied straight from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jackson/)). Same exception occurs even though I remove this code totally.

```
 public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> s = new HashSet<Object>();

        // Register the Jackson provider for JSON

        // Make (de)serializer use a subset of JAXB and (afterwards) Jackson annotations
        // See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations for more information
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        AnnotationIntrospector primary = new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector();//new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
        AnnotationIntrospector secondary = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
        AnnotationIntrospector pair = new AnnotationIntrospector.Pair(primary, secondary);
        mapper.getDeserializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);//setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().setAnnotationIntrospector(pair);

        // Set up the provider
        JacksonJaxbJsonProvider jaxbProvider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
        jaxbProvider.setMapper(mapper);

        s.add(jaxbProvider);
        return s;
      }
```

List of jackson-related JARs in my build path:

[image: list of jackson jar used]

For Apache wink, I have used:
wink, wink client, wink common and wink server jars (1.4).

The exception:

```
 16:39:18,143 INFO  [STDOUT] 16:39:18,142 ERROR [RequestProcessor] An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('c' (code 99)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests$LoggedServletInputStream@2ed482c6; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1433)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleUnexpectedValue(Utf8StreamParser.java:2090)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._nextTokenNotInObject(Utf8StreamParser.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:492)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2761)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2682)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:398)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ServerInjectableFactory$EntityParam.getValue(ServerInjectableFactory.java:200)
    at org.apache.wink.common.internal.registry.InjectableFactory.instantiate(InjectableFactory.java:68)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:44)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Things to consider:

In adapter code, inside parameter  `parameters:{“commonname": username, "password" : password }` , the first character fails all the time. This time it was `c` , so it failed with `c` (code 99 is corresponding `ASCII` value of `c`).

If it'd be: `parameters:{“username": username, "password" : password }`, it will fail with `u` and the corresponding code changes to its `ASCII` value i.e. 117.

I also tried with single quote instead of double quote, no quote and escaping quote. Every time it fails on first character.
I also tried creating JSON explicitly and pass it as parameter like:

```
 var credentials = JSON.stringify({'username': username, 'password': password});

 parameters: {"credentials":credentials} //still fails in first char
 //also as parameters: {credentials} :
 //this fails in adapter itself for wrong type of parameter
```

What I think is:
Since it fails in parsing, I think either the way I am trying to send JSON from adapter is not a right way to do it or I have not registered Jackson properly such that it can not parse the JSON correctly. But I am totally lost where to look for this problem.

I really appreciate you all for spending time to read this long question and any helpful inputs.

Comment: Your `JSON` is not valid. Consider this: `{
    "commonname": "username",
    "password": "password"
}`

Comment: those username and password without quote are actually variables. sorry for confusion. missed that part while copying code.

Comment: But without quote marks these variables do not make valid `JSON`.

Comment: OK. will give it a shot. thanks for your valuable input @MichałZiober

Comment: Thanks @MichałZiober . That was the problem. As an alternate, created javascript object and then stringify , now its working. If you have time, please post the answer so that I can mark it as right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JSON` is not valid.  Consider this:

```
{
    "commonname": "username",
    "password": "password"
}
```

`"` mark is really needed.